# How to solve or detect a memory leak in Angular+?

Tags: angular, performance, memory-leaks, routes

We have an Angular 8 application. We are currently having performance problems within the application. The routing (navigation) goes overtime slower and slower. After each navigation the application slows down. (Also requests to the backend API become slower).

Are there any tools, so we can detect any kind of memory leak or any other kind of leak?

We have tried commenting out as much code as possible. So we are left with only some components. When navigating back and forward, the application still slows down.

I tried detecting the leak with the memory snapshots you can take with Google Chrome.

memory before: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF1hf.jpg)

memory after: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m4Va.jpg)

I notice the "SafeSubscriber" & "FilterSubscriber", but I am not aware if this can cause these problems or how to solve these.

Comment: You are not unsubscribing somewhere.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Can we detect this in some way, what we are not unsubscribing? This is not a small project and we failed to find any subscribtion that is not unsubscribed.